# App functionality to create read or delete phone contatcts

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am asked to create functionality so that all app user contacts will transfer to phone contacts. It is business management system so they have many contact persons in the app (clients, workers suppliers etc.). To get contacts list, add or edit them is simple i found:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider

It should help with getting contacts list, adding new or editing. But I need delete functionality. I couldn't find it anywhere. Anyone has suggestions how I could do that? Maybe there are some libraries that could help me with this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a contact-id, here's how to delete a contact:

```
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
cr.delete(contactUri, null, null);
```